# rails - url_for behaving differently when using namespace (based on current controller being used)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

lets assume namespace is "abc", we have a controller "abcs" and another one that uses namespace "abc" is "defs".

for easy understanding:

```
AbcsController
Abc::DefsController
```

When current flow is in `AbcsController`, `url_for({:controller => "abcs", :action => :new})` is returning correct url but when flow is in `Abc::DefsController`, when I am giving:

```
url_for({:controller => "abcs", :action => :new })
```

It is treating it as:

```
url_for({:controller => "abc/abcs", :action => :new})  #Observe abc/abcs
```

So, here it should be "abcs" but not "abc/abcs" but it is treating like that.

Whats the solution? Please ask me fr more information.

Comment: That's the way a namespace works.

Comment: ok then, I am able to get solution by prefixing "/", is that the only solution ?

Answer (score 13):

From here:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

The last note box reads:

> If you need to use a different controller namespace inside a namespace
> block you can specify an absolute controller path, e.g: get '/foo' =>
> '/foo#index'.

This means all you have to do is this:

```
url_for({ controller: "/abcs", action: :new })
```

I ran into this problem as well and this solves it :)

Answer (score 5):

`url_for` also can take an array as an argument, you are probably looking for something like:

`url_for([:edit, :admin, @product])`

where the `admin` symbol would be your namespace.

Comment: How could I specify format using array parameter to `url_for`?