# Unexpected nested route generated using Rails url_for helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I'm using Rails 5 and my routes look something like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    namespace :admin do
      namespace :moderation do
        resources :templates
      end

      resources :users, except: [:new, :create] do
        namespace :moderation do
          resources :messages, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :update, :edit] do
            resources :message_replies, only: [:create, :edit, :update]
          end
          resources :templates
        end
      end

      root "home#index"
    end
end
```

I have `models/admin/user.rb`:

```
module Admin
  class User < ::User
  end
end
```

And `models/admin/moderation/template.rb`:

```
module Admin
  module Moderation
    class Template < ::Moderation::Template
    end
  end
end
```

Now when I try to generate the right route using `url_for` helper:

```
2.4.1 (main):0 > admin_user = Admin::User.first
2.4.1 (main):0 > admin_moderation_template = Admin::Moderation::Template.first
2.4.1 (main):0 > url_for([admin_user, admin_moderation_template])
NoMethodError: undefined method `admin_user_admin_moderation_template_url' for main:Object
```

Instead of getting `admin_user_moderation_template_url` I got `admin_user_admin_moderation_template_url`. Any help of how should I generate the right route in this case?

Comment: I just done `rake routes` with your code and either `admin_user_moderation_template_url` or `admin_user_admin_moderation_template_url` are *not valid urls* according to the output.

Comment: @Pavan thanks for your willing to help. I just updated the routes with the exact code I have, can you see if you can generate the right URL now?

Comment: Now i see `admin_user_moderation_template` in the `rake routes` output.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could resolve using this `xxx_url()` helper. In your case it'd be:

```rb
admin_user_moderation_template_url( user_id: admin_user.id, id: admin_moderation_template.id )
```

.

#### EDIT

Unfortunately I cannot try it as I would have to build the app you are working on. But as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20058406/1498118) you can use symbols to create `admin_user_moderation_template_url`.

Try to run the following line and tell me if it works (I'm not sure `user_id` is in the right position, but it might work).

```rb
url_for( [:admin, :user, :moderation, :template, user_id: admin_user.id, id: admin_moderation_template.id ])
```

You need also an association between User and Template to be able to link them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I need a generic way as sometimes I use dynamic resources (not always admin_user and admin_moderation_template). I have a model to generate the url and I include it whenever needed so I want to use `url_for`

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The point is that I don't know the resources all the time, Like it's not always admin_user and template. I want to have something generic like `url_for(model_1, model_2)` in which it returns the right route.

Comment: I have another hint, but before I shoot it I wonder: did you set the association between `Admin::User` and `Admin::Moderation::Template`?

Comment: Actualy there is no association between booth tables.

Comment: This might be the cause. Nested resources are useful only if you have an association. Looking at the way you set the routes `Template` belongs to one or many `User`. Set the association and then try to run the `url_for()` command again and them let me know what output you received.